# SQL command parameters addition works with Dictionary type but not with List collection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a common `ExecuteQuery` function which returns a dataset. I am trying to pass parameters as a list rather a dictionary which is commented. But for some reason unable to figure out that when I pass as dictionary the function returns data (commented code) but with list parameters, it is unable to do so.

Can someone please point out what could be the issue?

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public DataSet ExecuteQuery(string connName, string sp, List<SqlParameter> params)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(connName))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = sp;
                     
            // SqlParameter sql = new SqlParameter();
            // sql.ParameterName = "@id";
            // sql.DbType = DbType.String;
            // sql.Value = "123456";
            // Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> params = new Dictionary<string, SqlParameter>
            // {
            //    { "@id", sql }
            // };

            // foreach (var i in params)
            // {
            //    cmd.Parameters.Add(i.Value);
            // }

            foreach (var i in params)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(i);
            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work.  Are you getting an exception?  Can you provide a complete repro?

Comment: I think you want `cmd.Parameters.Add(i.Key, i.Value);` since there is no [SqlParameters.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) overload that accepts a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: @DanGuzman `Add(i.Value);` adds the `SqlParameter` value though...

Comment: I can see no reason for that, indeed, but: you are doing this *way* the hard way; have you heard of Dapper? it exists entirely to make this a breeze: `var data = connection.Query<SomeType>("someproc", new { id = 42, name = "abc" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();` - two named parameters, job done, and much more efficient than using `DataTable`